# yield keyword Question (run functions tough different files)

Tags: python, function, yield

I'm not sure if yield is what i need if i want to implement following logic

```py
def function():
  items = ["1", "2", "3"]
  for item in items:
    print(item)
function()
```

Now this will run the first line on execution first, now in case i want to run the function again if a specific if statement is ran, it use the first line. what should actually happen is to run the next line on each call:

```py
if ... is None:
  function() # choose second item, ifstatement is executed again, choose third item etc...
```

Hope anyone could help me there (i wrote following in github copilot and it suggeted me following pice of code and i'm not sure if that's what i need):

```py
# for loop, which don't use the first line on every execution and if the function is called a second time, the forloop will start from the second line within a file called lines.txt
def getline():
    with open('lines.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

Comment: The question doesn't show any research effort. Consider searching for similar problems before asking.

Comment: @SamAct
Thank you for your comment but i've done some research.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are looking for an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) over the list, and the way to get the next item is using the `next` function -

```py
items = [1, 2, 3]
item_iterator = iter(items)
print(next(item_iterator))
# prints 1
print(next(item_iterator))
# prints 2
print(next(item_iterator))
# prints 3
print(next(item_iterator))
# raises StopIteration
```